# Github page blog: html works ok but css and images are 404

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have my blog kray.me hosted on github pages for many years now.
There are others questions related to 404 errors related to Jekyll on SO but are related to case sensitiveness problems which is not the case here.

The site builds correctly locally.
However, on github.com, it seems that all the files located in my /public folder are not copied by Github page engine eg

https://github.com/Kraymer/kraymer.github.com/blob/master/public/img/back.jpg doesn’t result to http://kray.me/public/img/back.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK fixed I had a public repo named "public" that  interfered with the "public" dir of the blog repo